# How to make better timeseries plot of over 20 years?

Tags: r

My aim is to create monthly time series of data spanning 22 years. there will be 3 lines in the plot. `> dim(FINALDF) [1] 7670    4` one column has date value.

This is my first approach

```
dfmelt<-melt(FINALDF,id.vars="Date")
ggplot(dfmelt,                           
   aes(x = Date,
       y = value,
       col = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image: first plot using ggplot]

I also did the following in hopes of making it better.

```
value = c(mean(dfmelt$value[1:5]))
dates = c(as.Date(dfmelt$Date[1]));
for (i in seq(6,23010,5)) {
  value = c(value, mean(dfmelt$value[i:i+5]));
  dates = c(dates, as.Date(dfmelt$Date[i]));
}


plot(dates, value, type="l")
```

havent color coded yet

[image: using mean to condense]

However I'm not satisfied with the output. Could you suggest any ideas on How i can plot the timeseries to give a better idea of the progression?

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your plot? It just shows your data as it is. It is a long time series with marked annual seasonal variation and is noisy. If you want to show a trend over time you might consider averaging by year before plotting? You haven't told us what your plot represents or what you are unhappy with, and we don't have your data, so it is not clear what you would like us to do here. Could you perhaps edit your question to be more specific about what you would like from an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron it just looks very congested and difficult to find a trend.  considering your suggestions, since this timeseries is only for month of JAN from 2000-2021, should I be averaging year-wise such that each year has one corresponding value?

Comment: @hat6ytrs, maybe separating into facets will look better, add this line and see if it is good enough for you: `facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3)`